# How to remove .php extension only for pages under a sub directory?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove .php extension for only pages under a subcategory folder of the website.

`currently: example.com/blog/my-first-blog.php`

`what i want: example.com/blog/my-first-blog/`

I have tried the following rule in .htaccess (placed in root) but it still shows .php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /blog/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out
I just had to create .htaccess file under the "/guide/" directory. with the following rule note `RewriteBase /guide/` for making sure it only removes .php under "/blog/" folder

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve result you want is building a routing.
Firstable, you need to rewrite all traffic to your index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Then, you need to write router that will be parsing URL paths.
The simplest example of router is:

```
$url = urldecode(preg_replace('/\\?(.*)$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

if ($url == '/contact/about') {
    include 'contact.php';
}
```

You can check how does it work in `PHP` frameworks to get a better solution, or use one of them.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, actually yes i agree with you, this becomes less painful when using laravel or php frameworks. but this is an old custom php site, which we don't want to mess up all urls to prevent hurting SEO. So I had to do it through htaccess

Comment: So, then you still can built a router XD. Not the best, because of architecture of this site, but anyway. This can help to remove those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.example.in/} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php $ http://www.example.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```